# Find all specific types, with reflection, in assemblies loaded by the application with .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, f#

Note: although the example code is in F#, I'm not specifically looking for a F# answer but for the .net calls I need to do, so an answer in C# or F# is fine.

I have a system where there are commands, for a chat bot, scattered in different part of the code.
I find, and register, them all through reflection using this code:

```
member private this.RegisterCommands() =
    let t = typeof<IBotCommands>
    t.Assembly.GetTypes()
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.GetInterface(t.Name) <> null)
    |> Seq.iter (fun x ->
        (
            let i = (Activator.CreateInstance(x)) :?> IBotCommands
            botCommands.[i.Name()] <- i
            i.Initialize(this)
        )
    )
```

It's in F#, but I think the method calls give away what it does if you're more familiar with C#.

So, I do Assembly.GetTypes, keep the ones where GetInterface has the interface name I'm looking for and then I instantiate them.

This works well, but only within its own assembly. My question is how can I expand this to all assemblies loaded by the app (but the system ones to not waste time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your user assemblies define an assembly level attribute - which you can check for, to decide further scan the library. This is more robust than figuring out which assemblies to black-list, for e.g., you may not want to scan `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
   Assembly
       .GetEntryAssembly()   
       .GetReferencedAssemblies()    
       |> Seq.map    (fun assm -> Assembly.Load assm.FullName)
       |> Seq.append (Seq.singleton (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()))
       |> Seq.filter (fun assm -> assm.IsDefined(useAttrib) )
       |> Seq.collect(fun assm -> assm.GetTypes())       
       |> Seq.filter (fun x -> interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(x))
       |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

If your requirements are going to be more complex in the future, it might be worth taking a look at MEF.

```
let catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("./")
let container = new CompositionContainer(catalog)
container.ComposeParts()

let instances = container.GetExports<IBotCommands, IBotCommandMetadata>()
```

Comment: The last line doesn't compile (the <> null since IsAssignableFrom returns a bool)

Comment: I tried: Seq.filter (fun x -> x.GetInterface(interfaceType.Name) <> null), but it is not returning anything, while it does in the original code; not sure why

Comment: additionally, GetReferencedAssemblies() doesn't return all the assemblies. Some do not show up they're used in the code, so this is not going to work, I need to find another strategy; in a weird way, the assembly executing that code doesn't show up in the list!

Comment: @Thomas doh! Shouldn't have been answering this late at night. Fixed sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies?view=netframework-4.8) on `t.Assembly`, filter out `System` references by their name and then [`Assembly.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.8) on the names to load a sequence of assemblies. From there you can do a `Seq.collect` on [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The other assemblies which implement the interface are the ones referencing `t.Assembly` - and not the other way around.